# What is the volume magnetization of Fe3O4 (magnetite) monodomains at room temperature?

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, magnetic-moment

Magnetite is great stuff for making ferrofluids and has a huge amount of literature. Yet I can't seem to find an answer to the simple question in the title. The magnetization of various bulk structures is endlessly reported, for example [here](http://iopscience.iop.org/0022-3727/40/19/001/pdf/d7_19_001.pdf). I am reluctant to extrapolate from that to the properties of individual domains, though.